# PDO Driver cannot connect to sql - using xampp

Tags: php, pdo, drupal-7, xampp

I have been looking for a solution for this for hours now and I found a lot of solutions, but unfortunately none of them worked.

The error I am getting is :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\sqlsrv\database.inc:124 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\sqlsrv\database.inc(124):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=l...', 'sa', 'PWHERE...', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\database.inc(1689):
>   DatabaseConnection_sqlsrv->__construct(Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\database.inc(1479):
>   Database::openConnection('xilenacc', 'default') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\database.inc(2350):
>   Database::getConnection('default') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire,
>   ...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\lock.inc(146):
>   lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...') #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\bootstrap.inc(433):
>   lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...') #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\bootstrap.inc(455):
>   DrupalCacheArray->set(Array) #8 [internal function]:
>   DrupalCacheArray->__destruct() #9 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\includes\database\sqlsrv\database.inc on line
>   124`

This is line 124 at database.inc:

```
 PDO::__construct($dsn, $connection_options['username'], $connection_options['password'], $connection_options['pdo']);`
    <br>
```

**Information on what I am using:**

- PHP Version: 7.0.25
- Mssql express 2016
- Windows Server 2012
- If I can provide further information, please let me know.

**What I tried:**

- Downloading SQLSRV30 from microsoft website and putting the extensions in php -> **Result: After putting the dll names in php.ini, I restarted apache and checked phpinfo(), I didn't find sqlsrv.**
- I double checked the information I have in settings.php - they are correct,
   I even tried changing my sql pw because I thought it might be causing this,
   but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using anything like `msphpsql` to help PHP talk to your server and SQL db?
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: No I'm not using `msphpsql`.

Comment: Are you using anything to let PHP talk to MSSQL?
[PDO_DBLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

Comment: No, I'm not using PDO_DBLib either. I'm not using anything to let PHP talk to MSSQL..

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of googling, I found a solution that actually worked even though it doesn't look so important.

The solution that worked with me is to install Microsoft Redistributable 2012. Kinda weird but worked!